# C# WPF Windows 8 WIFI status of toggle button

Tags: c#, wpf, wifi, windows-8.1, togglebutton

How to get WIFI toggle button status by C# WPF in Win8?

The toggle button is as follow...

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about custom style for toggle button, or about how to connect/disconnect wi-fi?

Comment: As picture, can i get "OFF" state by C# WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check radio state of Wi-Fi by [Native Wifi API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706556.aspx). Using some codes of [Managed Wifi API](https://managedwifi.codeplex.com/)  project, I wrote a sample.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using NativeWifi;

public static class WlanRadio
{
    public static void CheckInterfaceStates()
    {
        using (var client = new WlanClient())
        {
            foreach (var @interface in client.Interfaces)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine($"[{@interface.InterfaceName}]");

                foreach (var state in @interface.RadioState.PhyRadioState)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine($"PhyIndex: {state.dwPhyIndex}");
                    Trace.WriteLine($"SoftwareRadioState: {state.dot11SoftwareRadioState}");
                    Trace.WriteLine($"HardwareRadioState: {state.dot11HardwareRadioState}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When both software radio state and hardware radio state (it represents the state of hardware radio switch) are ON, Wi-Fi is ON. Otherwise, Wi-Fi is OFF.

Comment: Thanks @emoacht ...
I get code from [Download](https://managedwifi.codeplex.com/releases/view/7718)
The file does not include **RadioState** <br>
BUT... the code in [SourceCode](https://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) include **RadioState**...

I get newer code, and solved this issue, thanks a lot =)